Moving dependency management from child pom to parent pom
I have dependency management in child pom. How can I reference this from parent pom.
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

I tried moving this to parent pom and add this in child pom without version but child is unable to identify version
I tried moving this to parent pom and add this in child pom without version but child is unable to identify version
Is there a suggested way to use dependency management in child pom when we have parent pom?

Please show a full setup... what do you mean by parent and child pom? Do you have a multi module build?

@khmarbaise I am trying to create a new repo for parent pom for set of springboot projects to maintain dependency harmony.

Hm... there is already spring-boot-dependencies bom which contains already all deps from spring boot area... also the mentioned spring-cloud-dependencies... So you want to create your own parent pom for several project and not a parent pom within a mutli module build...... Most important then I recommend to define all plugins with appropriate configuration in there... and make the dependencies a separate part ...

You do not need to repeat the entry in the child POM, not even partially. Just move the entry to the parent and you'll be fine.

There are some dependencies in child pom without versions when I move this in parent pom those dependencies are unresolved.

I am just talking about the <dependencyManagement> entry that you shared in your question.
